# Join computer to a Domain hosted on a Domain Controller in Azure

Tags: azure, domain-controller

I've been searching for a way to have 2 Domain Controller VM's in Azure (No DC on premise and not Azure AD). 
What I did was, I created 2 VM's in Azure with a private subnet.
I made them Domain Controllers with the DNS name: ad.company.com. 
I own the company.com domain name, so I created a public DNS A record entry to the public IP of the Load Balancer on Azure.

This seems to work fine when I install IIS and load balance port 80. 
The default IIS website is shown when surfing to ad.company.com.
However I now try to add a computer here in the office to the Domain Controller. 
I've opened up the necessary ports in the Load Balancer but it doesn't seem to work.
I also disabled the Windows Firewall and Azure Network Security Group just for testing. 
I am able to resolve DNS names through the DC.

I don't find a lot of information on the internet about this setup. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this not possible.
The only was to fix this is to have a point-to-site vpn.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding Computer to domain controller make sure computer and domain controller are talking to each other to ensure this check with telnet from computer with domain controller ip on required ports

Mostly if you don't have any restriction  in network and able to reach domain controller in AZure from office computer then your should be able to add to computer and make sure dc domain name and Domin controller domain is same...

Comment: I have used Telnet to check the required ports and it should work. I also disabled the Windows Firewall and Azure Network Security Group just for testing.